# Why does my video.js player parse EIA-608 in-band captions from my stream on any desktop browser, but on mobile it doesn't?

Tags: javascript, video.js, closed-captions

I'm creating a page for live streaming using video.js version 7.5.4. We are broadcasting an HLS stream with in-band EIA-608 closed captions. The closed caption button appears and the closed captions themselves show up when selected when on desktop Safari, Chrome, or Firefox; but on none of the corresponding mobile variants. The stream still plays; just without the option to turn on captions.

I looked into the player object on the mobile side and the subtitle track is not only not displayed, but it has also does not appear in the object returned by `player.textTracks()`

https://codepen.io/idreier/pen/BeELYd

The video.js blog has a post, but it is old and the video used actually contains a WebVtt track and not EIA-608. https://blog.videojs.com/inband-captions-support-with-vhs/
Thanks for the help!